# Presenting current date in full text format

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5.3, php-carbon, presenter

I am using [jenssegers/date](https://github.com/jenssegers/date) and `carbon` to display current date and time.

I can display full date in textual way by use of this code:

```
echo Date::now()->format('l j F Y H:i:s'); // example from jenssegers docs
```

Now, in a  [Codrops demo](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/11/04/rain-water-effect-experiments/) the date is presented as

```
<div class="slide__element slide__element--date">Saturday, 25<sup>th</sup> of October 2043</div>
```

### My problem

How to build a helper to display the current date exactly in this fashion, including wrapping the `th` (or `nd`, `st`) with the `sup` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format("l j <\s\up>S</\s\up> F Y H:i:s")
=> "Friday 4 <sup>th</sup> November 2016 22:11:16"
```

Note the s and u are escaped.

`format()` takes a date formatting *string*, you can add whatever chars you want to that string, you just have to escape them if they match PHPs formatting string characters.